# How to convert string 1012020 to date 1/01/2020 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date

How to convert string `1012020` to date `1/01/2020` in SQL Server?

Having a real hard time with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your string is missing the first "0" character for some date, so I add 1 line to fix it:

```
DECLARE @yourdate VARCHAR(10)= '1012020'
SET @yourdate=RIGHT('0'+@yourdate,8)

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@yourdate,5,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@yourdate,3,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@yourdate,1,2) AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SUBSTRING`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp) to achieve it. [Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=893e7642e5d51a3e77c5acee51091677)
**Syntax**

> SUBSTRING(string, start, length)

- Use [Right()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_right.asp) to get `year`. As a result, `@Year = RIGHT(@strDate, 4)`
- Use `SUBSTRING()` combine with [`Len()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_len.asp) to get `month`. For example:

  - `@strDate = '1012020'`, the start index should be `2`
  - `@strDate = '21012020'`, the start index should be `3`

  ==> So as a result, we have `@Month = SUBSTRING(@strDate, LEN(@strDate) - 5, 2)`
- The length of `@Day` should be the rest of length `@strDate` subtract `length of year is 4` + `length of month is 2`, So as a result, we have `length = LEN(@strDate) - 6`

```
DECLARE @strDate Varchar(20) = '1012020'
DECLARE @Year Varchar(4) = RIGHT(@strDate, 4),
         @Month Varchar(4) = SUBSTRING(@strDate, LEN(@strDate) - 5, 2),
          @Day Varchar(4) = LEFT(@strDate, LEN(@strDate) - 6)

SELECT @Day + '/' + @Month + '/' + @Year
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @RJ.